# Unrecognized attribute 'configProtectionProvider' after encrypting app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I run the following method at the beginning of my application passing in a section living under applicationSettings:

```
public static void EncryptConfigSection(string sectionKey)
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionKey);
        if (section != null)
        {
            if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                if (!section.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
                {
                    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider");
                    section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
                    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of the section in the app.config:

```
<applicationSettings>
  <Example.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="Key" serializeAs="String">
      <value>Value</value>
    </setting>
  </Example.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

When I try to access any of the settings from the  section, I receive the following error:

> Unrecognized attribute 'configProtectionProvider'

This is a desktop application that needs to encrypt some settings when starting then decrypt when exiting.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to encrypt/decrypt the config file while the application was running and continue to read the values.

Although not what I wanted, the solution to the problem was to first encrypt/decrypt the .config before the application ran.

Here is another approach which I didn't do but seemed interesting:
[Encrypting Passwords in a .NET app.config File](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

I found this: http://andybrennan.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/unrecognized-attribute-configprotectionprovider-after-encrypting-app-config/. And it's solves the problem.

Just use this method as written on the blog:

```
private void ResetConfigMechanism()
{
    typeof(ConfigurationManager)
        .GetField("s_initState", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                 BindingFlags.Static)
        .SetValue(null, 0);

    typeof(ConfigurationManager)
        .GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                    BindingFlags.Static)
        .SetValue(null, null);

    typeof(ConfigurationManager)
        .Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.FullName ==
                    "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths")
        .First()
        .GetField("s_current", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                               BindingFlags.Static)
        .SetValue(null, null);
}
```

Invoke it after save/refresh the config.

Comment: Not a big fan of calling private properties and methods thru reflection, however this solution works very well and was the only one that fixed my issue (complex config schema with include files and settings.settings file in  some projects). Gave it an upvote for this reason. 
I made sure to document the usage in my code and noted that it should be re-tested everytime we will change .NET Framework's version, to make sure it still works and to check out if microsoft implemented a public way of doing the same thing.

Comment: I tried to get something working from the other answers working but this is the only thing that works consistently.

Comment: I would give 10 stars if it was allowed. This code snippet saved my day

Comment: saved my day thanks, quick dirty fix i hate it but it works.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get Rick Schott's answer working, with one important caveat - you cannot use the static version of [ConfigurationManager.GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx) to retrieve the section after the refresh - you have to use [Configuration.GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.getsection.aspx) instead.

Full code:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("passwordSection") as ConfigurationSection;

if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
{
    // Encrypt the section.
    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DPAPIProtection");
    section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

    // The passwords are now encrypted.
    // Refresh the *parent* of the section that your passwords are in.
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");

    // Now use Configuration.GetManager to retrieve the new password section.
    // This doesn't throw the Configuration Exception :)
    ConfigurationSection section2 = config.GetSection("passwordSection") as ConfigurationSection;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to this blog post, the fix is to call `RefreshSection()` on the parent:

```
RefreshSection("applicationSettings")
```

[Unrecognized attribute configProtectionProvider](https://web.archive.org/web/20131026131344/http://blog.whconsult.com/2009/04/07/UnrecognizedAttributeConfigProtectionProvider.aspx)

Comment: Rick, unfortunately this did not work. Not sure why. I tried several different ways. The only thing that works is if I encrypt the config then start the application afterward.

Comment: @GrandMasterT 2 years too late, but I managed to get Rick's answer working - see my answer for details :) Also, +1 for Rick for guiding me to the right place!

Answer (score 0):

This post just saved my day and just in case someone need a fix in vb and 2017

```
    Private Sub ResetConfigMechanism()
        GetType(ConfigurationManager).GetField("s_initState", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(Nothing, 0)
        GetType(ConfigurationManager).GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(Nothing, Nothing)
        GetType(ConfigurationManager).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(Function(x) x.FullName = "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths").First().GetField("s_current", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(Nothing, Nothing)
    End Sub
```