# "Unrecognized attribute 'configProtectionProvider'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."

Tags: encryption, config

I'm encountering the above mentioned error when my application is trying to access appSettings from the ConfigOverrides.config file. It is required for me to encrypt the config settings. To do this I have used the below mentioned command line.

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "*path where the config file resides*"
```

After running this command line in the cmd prompt the config values are getting encrypted as expected. But when I browse my application through the inetmgr I get the above error in the below mentioned line in the config file.

```
<appSettings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
```

Note: I am encrypting this file before placing it in the web folder in the server as I'm not doing it in the code. I'm encrypting it by running the cmd prompt in admin mode.

Edit:This question might seem like a duplicate one but it isn't. The reason is that every place I have searched a solution for the above error they have encountered this issue while encrypting it at the beginning of the application run. As suggested in the accepted answers here :
[Unrecognized attribute 'configProtectionProvider' after encrypting app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856951/unrecognized-attribute-configprotectionprovider-after-encrypting-app-config][1])
I am already encrypting it separately and then including it in the application's web folder. There is no code involved in the encryption of the config files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unrecognized attribute 'configProtectionProvider' after encrypting app.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856951/unrecognized-attribute-configprotectionprovider-after-encrypting-app-config)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, if you read the actual questions. Also, a "duplicate" comment nearly always simply halts all answers. I would've loved to find an answer for this question.